# Docker insecure registry pull doesnt work

Tags: docker

I have two systems OSX 10.14 and can't pull images from A to B where A runs an insecure registry like follows:

```
    docker pull 192.168.2.130:5001/php:php7
Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.2.130:5001/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

On A the daemon.json file looks like this:

```
   {
  "debug" : true,
  "experimental" : false,
  "insecure-registries" : [
    "192.168.2.130:5001"
  ]
}
```

The docker ps shows:

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ee7b5bc570e7        registry:2          "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   About an hour ago   Up 34 minutes       0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp   registry_nas
```

and docker info shows in the lower section:

```
HTTP Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3128
HTTPS Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3129
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 192.168.2.130:5001
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

Comment: Perhaps silly, but did you restart the docker daemon after adding your `insecure-registries` entry? (I assume so because of the last part, but its worth asking because the rest looks correct.)

Comment: `{ "insecure-registries":["192.168.2.130:5000"] }` if you pull image on `B` then you should add this in `B` not `A`. this is supposed on client side.

Comment: @Adii: That's do the trick! Txh

Comment: Welcome, posted as an answer, let accept the answer and know the community that the solution has been found :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `{ "insecure-registries":["192.168.2.130:5000"] }` on the client that will trust the insecure registry.

So if you pull the image in B then you should add this in B, not A, as B is the client in this case which is trying to pull the image from A.